# PHP 5.5.9 test failures and Internal Server Errors

Tags: php, compilation, plesk, opensuse

Firstly forgive me if my terminology isn't entirely accurate. I have only limited knowledge on this subject, but will best try to convey the problems we are having. My server administrator is trying to deploy php 5.5.9 on a live server. Originally the intention was to install php 5.4.x, but we opted for the latest version instead (a manual compile is required regardless due to the o/s)

**The O/S is OpenSuse 12.1 and the server is a Plesk server (Plesk Version 11.0.9) with Apache 2.2.1.** This particular o/s does not have the ability to update php automatically so everything has to be done manually. Since we didn't want to risk screwing up the server (currently running with php 5.3.8), we opted to install a second version of php alongside the current one. The instructions we followed are outlined here: http://kb.parallels.com/en/114753

After numerous failed attempts due to missing libraries during compilation, we were finally able to compile php 5.5.9 without error and then proceeded to run tests with 'make test'

Unfortunately, the test results came back with 32 failures and 20% of the total tests were skipped. A total of 13011 tests were done, 10410 of which were completed. The TEST SUMMARY can be downloaded from here: http://uploaded.net/file/v6ug55l8

Anyway, deciding we might aswell give it a try, we applied the changes as indicated in the first link above to the vhost.conf. However, it didn't work, and the vhost then returned Internal Server Errors for every page regardless of script or extension. The errors logs sadly do not indicate any errors, only a whole ton of internal server errors recorded by mod_security. We did notice a huge number of these in the error log: **Warning: SuexecUserGroup directive requires SUEXEC wrapper.**  But, it doesn't seem to be related, as the same error goes back several weeks.

So, we're stuck without any idea what to do next. Our next attempt will be to try and compile a php 5.4.x instead, as perhaps something is bumping heads with 5.5.9...

Any and all advice will be appreciated. As per the opening statement, I'm not an expert here, so if you need any additional information about the machine and it's server, feel free to ask.  Thankyou for your attention!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. The vhost's CGI-BIN needed to be CHMOD 755 and not 775.