# FastCGI error after PHP Upgrade

Tags: php, fastcgi, plesk, opensuse

As outlined in a previous question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21648349/php-5-5-9-test-failures-and-internal-server-errors) my server administrator recently tried to install php 5.5.9 (using a wrapper) alongside our current configuration, which is php 5.3.8. The o/s is Opensuse 12.1, and it's a Plesk server (11.0.9).

After a successfull installation and initiating the new configuration on a specific vhost, every php script throws out a 500 Internal Server Error. The Apache logs do not show any useful information, however we were able to get mod_sec to pickup a fastcgi error which is as follows:

**Apache-Error:

```
[file "fcgid_proc_unix.c"] [line 634] [level 4] [status 104] mod_fcgid: error reading data from FastCGI server


Apache-Error: [file "util_script.c"] [line 435] [level 19] Premature end of script headers: db.php**
```

This error appears only when 5.5.9 is active, and disappears as soon as we switch back to 5.3.8. This is the only lead we have to go on :(

We've also tried checking htaccess & permissions, so far no change.

Thanks!

Comment: So what does `db.php` script do? It appears you're doing bad things there.

Comment: What about PHP's error log?

Comment: The db.php script is just a component of a larger CMS. I should add that the ISE 500 occurs with ANY script, even if it's just a blank file with a .php extension. The only reason I included the fastcgi error is because it's the only unique message to occur when 5.5.9 is active. The PHP logs don't show anything out of the ordinary.

Comment: PHP-FPM has log of its own, enable it and check what it says. Did you compile PHP with `--enable-maintainer-zts`? Use `php-config --configure` to check if that configure option was used.

Comment: Will do. I've spotted another clue. Plesk still shows the php version as 5.3.8 for the vhost, while it should be 5.5.9?

Comment: We've tested with 5.4.x too, still the same ISE on every php document. Nothing in the apache logs! Sigh :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, finally.

In our case we had to CHMOD the cgi-bin for the vhost to 755 (it was 775). After that, smooth running!